# Can you match two sets of equal length, and how?

Tags: javascript, regex

Is it possible to create a regex to match two sets with equal length? For example: I would like to match `aabb` and `aaaabbbb` but not `aaaabb`. What I want is something like `[a]+[b]+`, but with with both of those having equal length, so something like `[a]{x}[b]{x}` where x is a possible length. Is it possible to do this with one javascript regex, should I use multiple regexes for the multiple possibilities (I dont think I will need to check for length 32 or higher) or should I code it in myself?

Answer (score 1):

You can just split the two strings and check if both contain the same letter.

```
var rgx = /^(.)\1*$/, // makes sure all the characters are same
    str = "aaabbb", // define your string
    len = str.length / 2, // divide the length by two assuming it is even
    firstHalf = str.slice(0, len), 
    secondHalf = str.slice(len);

var isValid = (rgx.test(firstHalf) == rgx.test(secondHalf));
```

Comment: I know that much, but thats not what I want. I want to match two seperated sets with equal length. I would for example like to match (((....))) or (((...)...))...)))

Comment: Acturely, I just ended up doing `var m1 = str.match(/a+/)[0]; var m2 = str.match(new RegExp("b{"+ m1.length +"}"))` (If I remember correctly didnt use new RegExp but just a substring but thats the general idea behind the solution)